# Vlookup for multiple columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to retrieve values (all the 'x') corresponding to a particular ID for different variables (B,C,D & E).

```
 ID     B   C   D   E           
1001    2   5   8   9          
1002    2   5   5   6
1003    2   2   2   3
1004    3   3   4   2
1005    0   6   7   5
1006    1   7   1   4

ID      B   C   D   E
1002    x   x   x   x
1005    x   x   x   x
```

I have several rows, so I used vlookup option in x and dragged it but the values are not consistent.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want vlookup to return multiple values? I don't think this will work. Is there some reason you cannot do more than 1 vlookup?

Comment: Can you show the formula you're using ? I believe you will need to use a vlookup for each value you want returned; if you drag the formula from the first column to the next, and you didn't have $ in the right spots on the vlookup that could cause a problem with inconsistent results.

Comment: what **specific** value(s) do you want to lookup for in the multiple scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be fairly straightforward VLOOKUP, may require adjustment based on the range you're using but:

`=VLOOKUP(_id_reference_, $A$2:$E$7, Column(), False)` should do it.  The important part in the formula are the `$` which retain absolute reference to Column A, and then in the second argument an absolute reference to the entire table A2:E7.  If you omit the `$` notation, then the range in the formula will "drag", which can yield inconsistent results.

[image]

Comment: Does it fulfill your requirement or still need further help? `@SAS Programmer`

Comment: Thank you harun24hr. It helps :)

Answer (score 0):

VLookup is good ONLY when you have rows to get the values from. For columns, you can use HLookup. Yet, in your example, you have rows and columns at the same time you want to get the values from. 
For this to work, there is another way to do this by using index(reference, match(),match()). You just enter the formula in ONE cell (with correct row/column fixing using F4) and then just copy the formula all the way down or to the right.

I have created an example Excel file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/bujn6wnkpuvdqpy/SOLUTION.xlsx?dl=0

Or you could have a look at the image below:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Tango_Mike :)

Comment: You can also use HLOOKUP for searching column values. Index+Match as you note is also very versatile.

Comment: @SASProgrammer, please mark one of the presented answers as you chosen answer, provided it fully solves your query.